# Как получить ошибку для каждого блока

Tags: html, jquery, css

Здраствуйте!

Как получить ошибку для каждого блока

На данный момент ошибка при неотмеченном `input[type="radio"]` - только для первого блока

А хотелось бы получить ошибку для каждого блока, если не выбран `input[type="radio"]`

В чем моя ошибка

Мой код - http://jsfiddle.net/q3qdm2Ld/

Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте такой скрипт

```
    $("#test_inner .test-item").each(function (e) {
        if (e != 0) $(this).hide();
    });

    $("#next-btn").click(function () {

        if ($("#test_inner .test-item:visible").next().length > 0)
        {
            if ($("#test_inner .test-item:visible input[type='radio']:checked").length > 0)
            {
                $('#test_inner .test-item:visible .test_required').hide();
                $("#test_inner .test-item:visible").next().show().prev().hide();
            }
            else
            {
                $('#test_inner .test-item:visible .test_required').show();
            }
        }
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w2zqa549/

Comment: Спасибо огромное! А не подскажите как в последнем блоке скрыть кнопку Send?

Comment: Попробуйте так http://jsfiddle.net/w0epvdz7/

Comment: Еще раз огромное спасибо за помощь